# Compare the coefficient in same part of the equations

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I want to use Mathematica to do certain calculations. Below is a minimal example, my goal is to solve the equations that result from comparing the coefficients of both polynomials

```
twoEqs = { (a + b + c) x^2 + (a c + b) x + d == 0,
  (a + k) x^2 + (a f + b) x + e == c x^2}
```

It's apparent that $$(a+b+c) x^2 + (ac+b)x + d=0, (a+k-c) x^2 + (af+b)x + e=0$$

The coefficient of $x^2$ part is $(a+b+c)==(a+k-c)$ and coefficient of $x$ shows $(ac+b) =(af+b)$ and $d == e$.

How can I get the results of coefficient equations?

And by the way, can I `Simplify` the `twoEqs[[2]]` as `(a + k -c) x^2 + (a k + b) x + e == 0` , I have use `Simplify[twoEqs]` but fails, maybe I need add some options in `Simplify` to set the equation orders?

Any Comments will be much appreciate!

Comment: Are you working with integration by parts or something like that?

Comment: @E.Chan-López Thank you for your edit and helpful answers! right, equations equal means their coefficients are same by parts, so I want take the coefficient equations to select exact parameters and finally make their equals.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

One possible way

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eq1 = (a + b + c) x^2 + (a c + b) x + d == 0;
eq2 = (a + k) x^2 + (a f + b) x + e == c x^2;
eq = First@eq1 - Last@eq1 == First@eq2 - Last@eq2;
(Thread@ApplySides[CoefficientList[#, x] &, eq]) // Column
```

Or

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eq1 = (a + b + c) x^2 + (a c + b) x + d == 0;
eq2 = (a + k) x^2 + (a f + b) x + e == c x^2;
eq = First@SubtractSides[eq1] == First@SubtractSides[eq2];
(Thread@ApplySides[CoefficientList[#, x] &, eq]) // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want the solutions for `{a, b, c, d, f, e}` without formulating/finding the equations, you can do

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eq1 = (a + b + c) x^2 + (a c + b) x + d == 0;
eq2 = (a + k) x^2 + (a f + b) x + e == c x^2;
eq = First@SubtractSides[eq1] == First@SubtractSides[eq2];
SolveAlways[eq, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I think getting the equations first and then solving them might be useful for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
twoEqs = {d + (b + a c) x + (a + b + c) x^2 == 0, e + (b + a f) x + (a - c + k) x^2 == 0}

Reduce[CoefficientList[twoEqs[[1, 1]], x] == CoefficientList[twoEqs[[2, 1]], x]]
(*(d == e && b == -2 c + k && a == 0) || (d == e && c == f && b == -2 f + k)*)
```